# Sage notebook server error when not logged in to host

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sage

I have a Sage notebook server that runs in a `screen` session on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (32-bit).  When I'm ssh'd to the machine, I can use my notebook in my browser as expected.  If I'm not ssh'd to the machine (but notebook server still running in `screen` session), I can still log in and open my notebook, but when I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in a compute cell, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_sage_input_3.py", line 8, in <module>
    _interact_.SAGE_CELL_ID=1
NameError: name '_interact_' is not defined
```

If I then go ssh back into the machine, I close and reopen the notebook (log out from the server is not necessary), and I can use compute cells normally again.  I don't even have to be attached to the `screen` session, just logged in to the host.

I thought the most likely culprit would be related to the [eCryptfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ecryptfs.html) of my home dir, so I created `/var/sage/sage_notebook.sagenb`, but I still get the error*.  Currently, the permissions are at `750`, but I also tried `777` without success.

The issue is clearly something that's missing when I'm not logged in, but I can't figure out what.  The server is a pretty vanilla, ext4 install.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

*Actually, I was getting permission denied errors when the notebook dir was in my home dir and I wasn't logged in.  The error shown is what I'm seeing now that I've moved to `/var/sage/...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from a sibling post I made at [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338747/72132).

I had moved the notebook dir out of my home dir, but Sage was still accessing its config in `~/.sage`.  `export HOME=/var/sage` worked; I'll probably create a separate user to run the server.